# HiQPfd can't access page because of authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, pdf

I am trying to download content of a page and convert it to a PDF using HiQPdf, however the page I am trying to access requires login permissions. When I run the code to try and download the content it displays the login page saying you do not have authentication to access this page.

Is it possible to send authentication with HiQPfd?

I was thinking of sending a parameter which lets you view the data temporally but any user could abuse this to view other users data

```
        htmlToPdfConverter.Authentication.Username = "username";
        htmlToPdfConverter.Authentication.Password = "password";
```

I was thinking that I could have the page accept two parameters, username and password and if they are authenticated, give access to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the FAQ: http://www.hiqpdf.com/FAQs.aspx

Once a user is authenticated, Forms Authentication maintains an authentication ticket in a cookie or in the URL so that an authenticated user does not need to supply credentials with each request. When you are already authenticated and you want to convert a page of the same application you can simply set the authentication cookie before converting the web page. The converter can be set to send the authentication cookie to the web server. A simple code to create a HTML to PDF converter object, set the forms authentication cookie and convert an URL to a memory buffer is given below:

```
HtmlToPdf htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdf();

htmlToPdfConverter.HttpCookies.AddCookie(
FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value
);
```